# How to split a string by several possible characters?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, ecmascript-6

Given the following string:

```
`cartwright.claude@yahoo.com\r
herminia.nolan@hotmail.com\n
xstokes@hotmail.com;
dameon85@jacobs.com;
camren86@gmail.com
preston13@jerde.org
kelley05@bosco.com,
vella46@gmail.com,
dhaag@hackett.com;
mreinger@gibson.com;`
```

I am trying to split the string by an array of characters `[', ', '\r', '; ', '\n', ' ']`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: `str.split(/[\s,;]+/)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.split(/[\s,;]+/)`. The downside is that it may leave an emtpy string at the end. To avoid that, you are probably better off with matching what you *do* want to get, i.e. using `str.match`:

```js
let str = `cartwright.claude@yahoo.com\r
herminia.nolan@hotmail.com\n
xstokes@hotmail.com;
dameon85@jacobs.com;
camren86@gmail.com
preston13@jerde.org
kelley05@bosco.com,
vella46@gmail.com,
dhaag@hackett.com;
mreinger@gibson.com;`;

let result = str.match(/[^\s,;]+/g);

console.log(result);
```